# How to tell if an infinite series sum will be rational or irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, logarithms, irrational-numbers

I plugged in the following series into a calculator: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})$$ and got a result of approximately $1.29686$. That's nice and all, but I want to know: is this result irrational or perhaps even transcendental? I know that the natural log of any rational number is transcendental, therefore every single term in the series is transcendental, but adding together transcendental numbers infinitely may yield rational sums, e.g. $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi(2n+1)} = 1/4$$ So how can I prove that my result, ~$1.29686$, is transcendental?

Comment: That is a very difficult problem. Very little is know about how to prove numbers are irrational or transcendental. For instance, we don't even know if $e+\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: You should replace $\pi$ with $\frac1\pi$ in your last equality.

Comment: You certainly can't prove a number is rational or irrational  based on an estimate value. If it is rational, you will probably have an elementary way of showing it, but if it is irrational, it will be harder, and if transcendental, even harder.

Comment: Your sum is $$\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) = \ln \left(\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}\right)$$  It should of course be transcendental, but AFAIK there is no proof.  BTW, it's approxaimately $1.301846399$, not $1.29686$.